# How to open link in the same window AS3

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get my code to open a link in the same window instead of a new one each time. This is the code I have at the moment. There are four buttons that when clicked open a link. I've added the SELF command to each but that has stopped working entirely. Please help?

```
 Mouse.hide();
cursor_mc.startDrag(true);

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

myButtonContact.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThereCont);
function goThereCont(e: MouseEvent) {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("I'VE HIDDEN THE LINK OBVIOUSLY");
    navigateToURL(request, "self");
}

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

myButtonStills.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThereStills);
function goThereStills(e: MouseEvent) {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("I'VE HIDDEN THE LINK OBVIOUSLY");
    navigateToURL(request, "_self");
}

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

myButtonAnim.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goThereAnim);
function goThereAnim(e: MouseEvent) {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest("I'VE HIDDEN THE LINK OBVIOUSLY");
    navigateToURL(request, "_self");
}

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

myButtonFilm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent){
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("I'VE HIDDEN THE LINK OBVIOUSLY");
    navigateToURL(request, "_self");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
navigateToURL(request,"_self");
```

Comment: Yeah, like GSaunders says, you're missing the underscore on your first "_self".